# Database Connection issue in Apache Superset

Tags: visualization, apache-superset

After entering the database (MySQL) host name (Localhost or 127.0.0.1) and Port number(3306), it shows the Port is closed.

I have tried using the other solutions and replaced the host name with "**host.docker.internal**". But it only works for one time and in one PC. again, in another PC, I installed Apache superset and tried to connect MySQL database using the same method. But it throws an error. How to resolve this? Can anyone clarify about connection databases especially MySQL database with Apache Superset without any errors.